# Extending Line Shape Element

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to animate a line which extends or retracts over time. I found a good solution but unfortunatly the line doesnt stay fixed it moves around as well. Maybe there is a better solution to my problem. I hope someone can help me.

```
    private function init():void{

        sh.graphics.lineStyle(1.0, 0x000000, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE);
        sh.graphics.moveTo(200,100)
        sh.graphics.lineTo(51,51);
        sh.graphics.endFill();

        addChild(sh);


        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
    }

    private function mainLoop(e:Event):void{
        sh.scaleX += 0.01;
        sh.scaleY += 0.01;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to move the `sh` display object, and draw from its origin (0,0):

```
private function init():void{
    sh.x = 200;
    sh.y = 100;

    sh.graphics.lineStyle(1.0, 0x000000, 1.0, false, LineScaleMode.NONE);
    sh.graphics.lineTo(51,51);

    addChild(sh);

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, mainLoop);
}
```

Notice that I removed the call to `moveTo` since the default is (0,0). I also removed the call to `endFill` since you are not doing any color fills, so it is not necessary.